# Is zero a valid cookie value for IN_MOVED_TO/FROM inotify events?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, inotify

The `inotify(7)` man page says the following about `struct inotify_event`'s `uint32_t cookie` member:

> **cookie** is a unique integer that connects related events. Currently this is used only for rename events, and allows the resulting pair of `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `IN_MOVED_TO` events to be connected by the application. For all other event types, cookie is set to 0.

Does `inotify` make any guarantees about *not* using 0 for move events? I'd like to do cookie matching and want to use a guard value for "cookie/event not yet found", and I'd like to be able to just use 0 for this to keep things as simple as possible. Thanks to anyone who has insight into this!

Answer (score 0):

The cookie **MUST NOT** set to 0 when IN_MOVED_FROM and IN_MOVED_TO events was generated. You can use the cookie to match which directory or file is moved in the watching directory. On the other events, the cookie **MUST** be set to 0.

Comment: thanks for the response. Can I ask what source/reference you're getting this from?